# How to insert commands for randomization and action after a given time

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

Right now in my code, I have it written out to play audio files after a !join command. I would like to change it to a command like after every 40 minutes, and I would like to be able to choose a random file to play out of a list. Help on how to ajust my code would be great!

My code:

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('AUDIO FILE')
        player = voice.play(source)
    else:
        await ctx.send("User not in a voice channel, unable to connect.")
 
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.voice_client):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I have left the voice channel.")
    else:
         await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel.")
 
 
 
client.run('BOT TOKEN')```
````

Comment: "a command like after every 40 minutes" What exactly does this mean? If for example you want the action to happen every 40 minutes *regardless of any command input*, then what you are trying to do is *schedule a task*, and there is [abundant documentation](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discord.py+schedule+task) on that out there already.

Comment: "I would like to be able to choose a random file to play out of a list." Okay, so *what exactly is the difficulty*? Are you able to create a list of file names? Are you able to figure out what file names should be in the list? Are you able to make a random choice from a list? If not, what happened when you tried using a search engine to look up whichever parts you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

First, in the top of the code add:

```
from discord.ext import tasks 
import random
```

then, add anywhere in your code:

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=40)
async def play_random_song():
    for channel in voicechannels: #voicechannels is your list of voicechannels where a random song should be played every 40 minutes
        song = random.choice(list_of_songs) #list_of_songs is your list of all the songs audio files you want to be able to be randomly played
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(song)
        player = voice.play(source)
```

then start the task you created in `on_ready`:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    play_random_song.start()
```

That means your final code is:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext import tasks 
import random 
 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('AUDIO FILE')
        player = voice.play(source)
    else:
        await ctx.send("User not in a voice channel, unable to connect.")
 
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.voice_client):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I have left the voice channel.")
    else:
         await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel.")
 
 
@tasks.loop(minutes=40)
async def play_random_song():
    for channel in voicechannels: #voicechannels is your list of voicechannels where a random song should be played every 40 minutes
        song = random.choice(list_of_songs) #list_of_songs is your list of all the songs audio files you want to be able to be randomly played
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(song)
        player = voice.play(source) 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    play_random_song.start()

client.run('BOT TOKEN')
```

References:

`random.choice`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

`discord.ext.tasks`: [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far! Just a quick beginner question- How do I create a list of voice channels? I know how to create a list but am unsure about **how to identify each channel.** Thanks again.

Comment: @SeñorEgg You can simply add the `channel` object to the list, like for example you have `channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel` and then you can simply do `voicechannels.append(channel)`

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but now I'm getting an error message saying "Instance of 'str' has no 'connect' member". How do I fix this?

Comment: @SeñorEgg Are you asking new questions below an answer that maybe did answer your first question? Please open another post for further question the next time as I guess Chuaat provided all that is needed.